# Change text for icons on hover and back to text on mouse out icons - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a text link, that when the mouse is on top, it chagnes to 3 icons showing social networks. The icons must be there while the mouse is on top of them and disappear to the text link state when the mouse is out.

Here is my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/eccg8/1/). I have some of the functionality, but it is buggy. The icons disappear when the mouse moves and flickers when the mouse gets still

Thanks for the help

**Here is the html**

```
<div id="text_links">
    <a href="#" id="projects_link" class="menu_link">PROJECTS</a>
    <a href="#" id="contact" class="menu_link">CONTACT</a>
    <a href="#" id="social" class="menu_link">FOLLOW US</a>
</div>
<div id="social_buttons">
    <a href="#" id="skype"><img src="http://ticketcomunicacion.com/ticket/data/social/facebook-logo.png" id="skype-btn"></a>
    <a href="#" id="tumblr"><img src="http://ticketcomunicacion.com/ticket/data/social/facebook-logo.png" id="tumblr-btn"></a>
    <a href="#" id="facebook"><img src="http://ticketcomunicacion.com/ticket/data/social/facebook-logo.png" id="facebook-btn"></a>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.menu_link {
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}



#skype-btn, #facebook-btn, #tumblr-btn {
    width: 24px;
}

#social_buttons {
    position: absolute;
right: 260px;
top: 5px;
}


.hidden { display: none !important; }
```

**And the JQuery**

```
$().ready(function() {

$("#social_buttons").hide();

$( "#social" ).mouseover(function() {
      $("#social").addClass("hidden");
      $("#social_buttons").fadeIn("slow");
      setTimeout(function(){
        $("#social_buttons").hide();
        $("#social").removeClass("hidden");
      }, 5000);
    });


      var s = null;
      $( "#social_buttons" ).mouseout(function() {

        clearTimeout(s);
        $("#social_buttons").hide();

        s = setTimeout('$("#social").removeClass("hidden");', 100);
      });
});
```

Comment: You don't need javascript to do this, you can use CSS

Comment: How could I do it with CSS?

Comment: start with simple css using the :hover state, e.g. `.menu_link:hover{background:red}` then look into CSS3 animations to achieve the fade in and fade out on and off hover.

Comment: The flickering is because when mouseover happens the element changes causing the cursor to come off it, so triggering mouseout, then mouseout it changes again and you're in a loop. So you need to make your icons and where the text would appear a fixed shape and size that doesn't change to avoid that.

Comment: Here look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/k759H/1/

Comment: I can't make it work with your example. I need one string that hides several icons, which are displayed when the string is hovered. I don't know how to change you example to do that with css

Comment: ok. I looked at the site. Maybe I looked at the wrong menu (specifics are very important). When you've learned about CSS you'll have a better idea what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this when with mouse out on social button:

```
$( "#social_buttons" ).mouseout(function() {
    clearTimeout(s);
    $(this).hide();
    //$("#social").removeClass("hidden");
    s = setTimeout('$("#social").removeClass("hidden");', 100);
  });
```

> [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/eccg8/4/)

Comment: Still has some problems, when the mouse is running from one social network to another, the flickering effect persist and there are times where the word follow us disappears. I'm trying to imitate the behavior of the social networks in this page: http://24hoursofhappy.com/

Comment: I finally got it. I changed the mouseout for a mouseleave and everything works fine now. There's no flicker effect. Thanks

Comment: Well done! While I'm trying to float a tag in #socialbutton div float left to fit whole div content.